# Clang breaks with CMake on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, clang

Let me outline the scneario:

1. I have very basic C++ files in windows:

   ```
   foo.cpp // Has int main(), includes bar.hpp
   bar.cpp
   bar.hpp
   ```
2. I setup clang through Visual Studio, following the [LLVM "Using Visual Studio" guide](https://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html) along with the appropriate PATH variables:

   ```
   clang++ --version

   clang version 18.0.0 (https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project.git 81d04709f86968431ecab1df12a17279d057daa9)
   Target: x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
   Thread model: posix
   InstalledDir: C:\llvm-project\build_vs\Release\bin
   ```
3. The code compiles manually with clang and produces a binary a.exe:

   ```
   clang++ .\bar.cpp .\foo.cpp
   ```

The issue is that I can't seem to get this setup working in CMakeLists.txt. I've tried a number of things, and this is my CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.28.0)
set(CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE_TARGET_TYPE "STATIC_LIBRARY")
project(CMakeProjectCpp VERSION 0.1.0 LANGUAGES CXX)

include(CTest)
enable_testing()

set(CPACK_PROJECT_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})
set(CPACK_PROJECT_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION})
set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)
set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

set(SOURCES
    foo.cpp
    bar.cpp
    bar.hpp
)

set(CMAKE_GENERATOR "Ninja")

add_executable(CMakeProjectCpp ${SOURCES})

if(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID STREQUAL "Clang")
    target_compile_options(CMakeProjectCpp PRIVATE
        -Wall
        -Wextra
        # Add other Clang-specific flags
    )
endif()
```

It works just fine for g++, which is

```
g++.exe (xPack MinGW-w64 GCC x86_64) 13.2.0
```

And runs a very simple build command, builds the two object files then the executable.

```
C:\cmake-3.28.0-rc1-windows-x86_64\bin\cmake.EXE --build c:/codebase/build --config Debug --target all --
[build] [2/3  33% :: 0.314] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/CMakeProjectCpp.dir/bar.cpp.obj
[build] [2/3  66% :: 0.328] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/CMakeProjectCpp.dir/foo.cpp.obj
[build] [3/3 100% :: 0.733] Linking CXX executable CMakeProjectCpp.exe
[driver] Build completed: 00:00:00.772
[build] Build finished with exit code 0
```

When I change the kit to clang in Vscode, it fails:

```
[build] [3/3 100% :: 0.532] Linking CXX executable CMakeProjectCpp.exe
[build] FAILED: CMakeProjectCpp.exe 
[build] C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /C "cd . && C:\llvm-project\build_vs\Release\bin\clang++.exe -fuse-ld=lld-link -nostartfiles -nostdlib -O0 -D_DEBUG -D_DLL -D_MT -Xclang --dependent-lib=msvcrtd -g -Xclang -gcodeview -Xlinker /subsystem:console CMakeFiles/CMakeProjectCpp.dir/foo.cpp.obj CMakeFiles/CMakeProjectCpp.dir/bar.cpp.obj -o CMakeProjectCpp.exe -Xlinker /MANIFEST:EMBED -Xlinker /implib:CMakeProjectCpp.lib -Xlinker /pdb:CMakeProjectCpp.pdb -Xlinker /version:0.0   -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32 -loldnames  && cd ."
[build] clang++: error: unable to execute command: program not executable
[build] clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

It is very odd and my current theory is that it is adding MSVC variables to the link command. Is there anything that explicitly needs to be added to the CMakeLists.txt file?

Comment: VSCode is an advanced IDE, that requires complex configuration and existing knowledge of complicated, specialized technologies, like JSON, to work correctly. It is designed for experienced developers that have a wide existing domain of technical knowledge. It is often found to be too complicated and confusing for beginners, who will find other, simpler tools easier to use, like Visual Studio Community Edition on MS-Windows, and emacs+make on Linux.

Comment: Does CMake work when ran directly from the terminal?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik What makes you think OP is a beginner?

Comment: What makes you think the OP is not, @HolyBlackCat?

Comment: No it does not @HolyBlackCat. Same scenario as above, and doesn’t matter what generator I use between Ninja and Unix Makefile.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I’m not a beginner, but I am new to developing in windows. I want to ensure my project can be built with multiple compilers. The editor is fairly irrelevant at this point because I can’t get cmake working from command line anyway.

Comment: If you compile something with Clang manually, does it execute correctly from the console? What flags do you pass to CMake?